# next setting is not tomorrow

Tags: pyephem

trying to compute the time for Sun's next setting time, I obtain a value for tomorrow - but I'm computing while the Sun is surely above of the horizon!

m is my observing site; that's what I got on terminal:

```
>>> ephem.now()
2012/10/16 16:02:00
>>> print m.next_setting(ephem.Sun(), use_center=True)
2012/10/17 16:38:36
```

that's the time for tomorrow. Also:

```
>>> m.previous_setting(ephem.Sun()) < ephem.now()
False
>>> m.previous_setting(ephem.Sun())
2012/10/16 16:42:14
```

So previous_setting is in the future.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Could you share the code that creates `m` your observing site?

Comment: `m=ephem.Observer()`  
`m.long='7:42:00'`  
`m.lat='45:04:00'`

Answer (score 0):

The `next_setting()` and `previous_setting()` functions do **not** consult the current value of `ephem.now()`. Instead, they look for dates previous to or subsequent to the `.date` of the `Observer` object — so the results you are getting only happen in my own experiments here on my laptop if the observer `.date` somehow gets set to a day in the future. Here are the setting times that I get if I use exactly the date and time you supplied:

```
import ephem
m = ephem.Observer()
m.long = '7:42:00'
m.lat = '45:04:00'
m.date = '2012/10/16 16:02:00'

print m.next_setting(ephem.Sun(), use_center=True)
# --> 2012/10/16 16:40:27

print m.previous_setting(ephem.Sun())
# --> 2012/10/15 16:44:05
```

Could you try running this script and see what you get as a result? The `ephem.__version__` that currently displays on my laptop is 3.7.5.1, just in case that is a difference between us.

So: if you see odd results like this, then instead of printing and comparing the value of `ephem.now()` with the sunset times, you need to investigate the relationship between the observer's `.date` attribute and the sunset times you get out. If you can produce a little sample script like the one I show above, that sets its own times, instead of relying on `now()` to show a mistake that PyEphem is making (since by the time I see your question, my `now()` is obviously a bit different from your original "now"!), then I'll do my best to track down the problem.